# How do I check the continuity of this function?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, continuity

I am doing basic calculus, can someone tell me how to find the continuity here at $x=1$

$f(x)=\begin{cases}5x-4 & 0<x \leq 1\\4x^2 -3x & 1 < x < 2.\end{cases}$

Comment: Note how I formatted the piecewise function here, for future reference.

Comment: I am still learning Tex

Comment: It's all good. I've been using it for years, and I'm *still* learning new things about it.

Comment: An equation is not the sort of thing that can be continuous. The question is really about whether a particulat *function* is continuous. It's important to pay attention to terminology becaue the terminology reflects the concepts required to address the question.

Comment: @CarlMummert I told you I was a *beginner*, anyway edited the title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b$, let $I=(a,b)$, $c\in I$, $f:I\to\Bbb R$. Then we say that $f$ is continuous at $c$ iff $$f(c)=\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x),$$ that is, iff the left and right limits exist, and are both equal to $f(c)$.

In this case, coming toward $c=1$ from the left, what does $f(x)$ look like--that is, how is $f(x)$ defined for $x<1$? What about from the right?

Comment: I get it, as we move closer to the point on the graph from both sides, the net result must be zero ! *must not miss classes*

Comment: Well, not *zero*, but the same. In this case, all three are equal to $1$, so it is indeed continuous at that point. Not missing classes is certainly a good plan.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that both functions are continuous separately over $\Bbb R$: the problem is continuity at $x=1$. So just make sure that the limits from the right and left of $1$ of$ f(x) = f(1)$.

Comment: In which equation must I check the left and right limits ?

Comment: So f(1) = 1 for both functions, so that's good.

Comment: You need to check limit as x goes to 1 from left of 5X-4 =1,

Comment: And, you need to check that limit as x goes to 1 from right of 4X^2-3X = 1

Comment: So I must substitute 1 in both functions because they deal with different ranges... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The function is continuos because it is both right continuous and left continuos at f(1) where x=1
The limit 5x-4      =1
      As  x tends to 1
The limit 4x²-3x  =1
   As x tends to 1
So the function is both left continuous and right continuous hence generally continuous at x=1